# How to define a @Value property as optional?

Tags: java, spring

The following does not work. But how could I then define optional `application.properties`?

```
@Value("${my.property}")
private Optional<String> property;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [How to define @Value as optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348061/how-to-define-value-as-optional) , you can define a property's default value as null:

```
@Value("${myValue:#{null}}")
```